# Java error Caused by: Javax.net.ssl.SSLHandhakeException: Java.security.cert.CertificateExpiredException

Tags: java, ssl

We are having a problem with absorbing data from several FTP servers (hosted by a third paty) Our system is unable to absorb any files from the FTP servers while we are able to reach them via FileZilla. Other systems are able to reach them and place the files on the path, but our system will not pick them up and gives an error: 
Caused by: Javax.net.ssl.SSLHandhakeException: Java.security.cert.CertificateExpiredException
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eyIzQ.png)
Is someone able to advise us as all parties are saying it is not caused by them; 
The Website hosting says its not caused by them, the FTP hosting says its not caused by them, and the developpers are also saying it is not caused by them :(

Comment: It would be nice to have your error logs copied under your question.

Comment: please also post some sample code!

Answer (score 0):

> Certificate Expired Exception. This is thrown whenever the current
>   Date or the specified Date is after the notAfter date/time specified
>   in the validity period of the certificate.

Check if your application server and FileZilla try to access the same server.
If so, then you might need to update the certificate in the trust store of your application server. (The certificate might have been added to the machine from which you are using FileZilla - as far as I understand these 2 are different machines).

Comment: Thanks so much for all your reply's. I am sorry for not having added all the required infii, as you might have noticed I am not actually a developper - Just the middle man. My colleage developper could unfortunately also not find the solution.

Answer (score 0):

The error is clear about the certificate expiration. Hence, either FileZilla is ignoring that error, or it's using another certificate. So you have 2 options: either ask your developers to ignore the certificate as well, or to ask for updating the certificate on the other side.

Answer (score 0):

In the end, it turned out the Root SSL certificate of the FTP host was indeed expired. This seems to be a rare situation.